# Jekyll equivalent of Hugo's "with"

Tags: jekyll, liquid, hugo

In Hugo, one can use `with` to avoid repeating variable names.

```
{{ with .Site.Params.foo }}
<p>{{ .bar }}</p>
{{ end }}
```

This is almost equivalent to

```
<p>{{ .Site.Params.foo.bar }}</p>
```

What would be its equivalent in Jekyll?

My try:

```
{%- assign tempvar = .Site.Params.foo -%}
<p>{{ tempvar.bar }}</p>
```

Comment: Is Liquid's for loop code example similar what how you are using `with` in Hugo?  https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#for.  I see some similarities in Hugo's `with` rebinds the context (.) within the `with` scope like Liquid's ability to bind scope by explicitly defining `product` in `{% for product in collection.products %}`

Comment: @Kin Thanks for your observation.  I've finally found the related documentation for [`with`](https://gohugo.io/functions/with/#readout), which is rather a shorthand of an `if` statement and `assign`. You're right about the scope-binding effect of `for`. To put it into practice, I'm facing this situation: If a `for` loop through `collection.products` has to be used for a particular object, say `collection.products.gold`, I'll first need to make sure there's no other stuff like `collection.products.shxt`, so the loop has one iteration. Thanks for link to Liquid docs, perhaps there's better a way

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
{%- assign tempvar = site.foo -%}
<p>{{ tempvar.bar }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your follow up comment to the question, it looks like you are seeking a way to check if a variable only contains a desired key:value pair.  Here is one way to check if a variable contains only the desired key.

```
            {% assign numOfKeys = page | size %}
            {% assign sizeOfGold = page.gold | size %}

            <!-- Print out the page object for debugging purposes -->
            {{ page | inspect }}

            {% if numOfKeys == 1 %}
                {% if sizeOfGold > 0 %}
                    {% for x in page.gold %}
                        <!-- Logic -->
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
```